# WeChat For PC on LMDE5

Tags: ubuntu, debian

It seems that I am chasing a ghost.   Been at it for a few hours.

Might someone in the entirety of the digital multiverse posses complete instructions for how to successfully install  WeChat for PC (WeChat.exe) on Linux Mint Debian Edition 5 (Debian 11 Bullseye)?

All instructions assume Ubuntu, but LMDE5 can't use Ubuntu PPAs, so I seem to be stuck

I use the English version, plus a Chinese input on Ubuntu... transitioning to LMDE5.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the Windows executable WeChat.exe on Linux, install Wine. You can get it with `apt`. According to WineHQ App list [WeChat should work](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=16931).

Alternatively you can try another messenger app. Rambox [supports WeChat](https://rambox.app/apps/), you can find a WeChat plugin for [Pidgin](https://www.pidgin.im/) in [GitHub](https://github.com/sbwtw/pidgin-wechat) - it's probably available for other Linux messaging applications as well.

Yet another option is [electronic-wechat](https://github.com/geeeeeeeeek/electronic-wechat). That's another GitHub project, but no longer under development. It was archived 2018. [weweChat](https://github.com/trazyn/weweChat) is active and is also available as [AppImage](https://appimage.github.io/weweChat/). No updates since 2019 either, so either nothing has needed updating or the project is abandoned.

Or you can use the Ubuntu PPA to [build a Debian package](https://wiki.debian.org/CreatePackageFromPPA).

Comment: thanks for the reply....  it seems I have hit the wall once again.  
1.electronic-wechat does not work
2. Likewise for weechat 
3. Previously used Rambox, but my individual threat  vector is far too high for Rambox or even Pidgin right now.. (long story) I need good old-fashion original code.
4. WineHQ info is just wrong, they support QQ not wechat
So at this point it appears that I need to a.) use the Ubuntu PP to build a Debian package or resolve a bug that I ran into on a previous install attempt.  thanks again for the effort.

Comment: @mjones 4. Really? That's not the only thing wrong then, download from https://pc.weixin.qq.com/?lang=zh_CN is WeChatSetup.exe.

Comment: Yes, really... I have wine installed... no wechat.  I have also followed 2 sets of chinese language instructions (I read Chinese, live in China.), They both requiring downloading as you suggested.... except I when I do... I complete everything as instructed.... there's a fatal error... in any case I will take another shot at it before bed and post the bug... maybe someone in this group can spot a fix... fingers crossed.

Comment: Hum. In that case I'd go for building from the PPA.

Comment: here's my bug: 
https://superuser.com/questions/1778754/lmde5-wine-8-wechat-fatal-error